# I got products in console in redux actions but When i use same funtion in component and try to get products by useselector hook i got undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, mern

This is an API call and in console, i get all products . But when I use the same `getProducts` function in components I got undefined in console

```
export const getProducts = ()=> async(dispatch)=>{
    try {
        const data = await fetch("http://localhost:80/api/products/getallproducts",{
                method:"GET",
                headers:{
                    "Content-Type":"application/json"
                }
        });

        const res = await data.json();
        console.log(res);
        dispatch({type:"SUCCESS_GET_PRODUCTS",payload:res});
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({type:"FAIL_GET_PRODUCTS",payload:error.response});
    }
}
```

I use it on Home page and got undefined instead of products as i am using same  function of `getProducts`

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import Categories from '../components/Categories'
import Banner1 from '../components/Banner1'
import MaterialUiaresoul from '../components/MaterialUiaresoul'
import ProductSlide from '../components/ProductSlide'
import FeaturedProducts from '../components/FeaturedProducts'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getProducts } from '../redux/actions/action'



const Home = () => {


  const  products  = useSelector(state => state.getproductsdata);
  console.log(products)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
   <>
      
        <MaterialUiaresoul/>
        <ProductSlide/>
        <Banner1/>
        <Categories/>
        <FeaturedProducts />
      

   </>
    
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: You are not showing your store configuration and reducer, so it's pretty much impossible to spot the error here. Generally though, you are writing a style of Redux that is outdated since 2019 and about 4 times the amount of code of modern Redux. Please read [up on modern Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and follow [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) instead whichever tutorial you follow now.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to dispatch something that is not redux action.

Let's see, you are trying to call this line `dispatch(getProducts());`
After `getProduct` call, it will return a new async function, that doesn't called and expect `dispatch` to be passed in it.

Normally actions look like this:

```
export function addTodo(text) {
  return { type: ADD_TODO, text }
}
```

Its just a function that return a plain object with type as a required property.

When dealing with api calls using redux, its better to look into some libraries that will help you, such as redux-thunk or redux-saga for example. Redux actions sync by default and async behavior can be reached with use of some middlewares.

In your example, you can make your code work as expected if you will run your `getProduct` function, and then run response from it with `dispatch` passed as first argument:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const createApiCall = getProduct();
createApiCall(dispatch)
```

I'm still not sure whether it will work and recommend you to look at redux-thunk. Its pretty easy to learn and use.

Comment: They are dispatching a thunk, which is totally fine. A thunk should be dispatched and not called.